# Как запретить пользователю изменять размер нового окна?

Tags: javascript

```
function open_window(link,w,h) 
{
    var win = "width="+w+",height="+h+",menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes";
    newWin = window.open(link,'newWin',win);
    newWin.focus();

}
```

пробовал ставить newWin.resizable(no);  ничего не выходит

Comment: `resizable=yes` явно говорит что можно изменять размер. И вообще это от браузера зависит, некоторые могут плевать на свойства указанные в параметрах

Comment: Лиса "плюёт" на эти параметры. Есть какой-то выход из данной ситуации?

Comment: написать свой браузер :-)

Comment: @Grundy, восхитительно :) Может ловить событие скролла и отменять его?

Comment: Никак. Вы не должны этого хотеть

Comment: @AlexeyTen почему это не должен? Или это где-то прописано в документации какой-то? ткните носом, пожалуйста

Comment: Потому что это плохо и мешает пользователям. Сайты не должны решать какого размера у меня окно и уж тем более не должны решать как я его буду изменять. Это просто глупость и плохой тон.

Comment: @AlexeyTen как говориться "На вкус и цвет, товарищей нет", а должны ли сайты решать какого размера окно - дело разработчика

Comment: Ну вот, разработчики браузеров решили, что первоначальный размер вы задать можете, а невозможность его изменить нет. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=177838